# How can I access a website without it being able to identify me as a previous visitor?

Tags: web-browser, vpn, anonymity

Phone is rooted

Basically I want to be able to access a website without it being able to determine any of the things it dermined about me (my device, ip address etc) when I accessed it last, no matter how advanced of a tracking mechanism it uses.

I want it to seem as if it is being accessed from a different device, completely unrelated to the device which I accessed it from previously. No connection between the two could be made.

An app called XprivacyLuna through Xposed comes to mind, but not sure if it could get around fingerprinting.

Comment: *"... __no matter how advanced__ of a tracking mechanism it uses. ..."* - With such an unspecific and also unrealistic requirement you need to take unrealistic measures: simply use a new device where you also not logged in somehow as the same user and best also from a different location and with a different SIM from a different mobile provider where you have given different identities when buying the SIM. There might be easier ways with less generic requirements though.

Comment: Using different VPN and incognito browsing for each session should be enough or you can just use Tor.

Comment: The "easy" way: using Tor + the Tor browser because it is set up against fingerprinting. However, many websites will refuse visitors coming through a Tor exit node.

Answer (score 1):

What you expect can be done, but will not be convenient.

It's not needed to create a new fingerprint for every connection, but have one fingerprint that are so generic it cannot be linked to you.

You can buy a popular phone - a cheap Samsung (for example) running the stock ROM (not rooted), and access the site using your provider. For the next access, factory reset, access the site using a WiFi connection. Even if the device is the same, the factory reset will delete every identifier linked to the device, and more than a dozen popular Android devices running the stock firmware will have accessed the site, so neither access can be linked to you.

That's why Tor browser recommends you to not change the browser resolution and not used it maximized, so every user will have the same settings and same resolution.